# Every subspace of a vector space has a complement

Tags: vector-spaces

I want to see if my proof is true or I thought very trivially?

If $H$ is a subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $V$, show there is a subspace $K$ such that $H\cap K=0$ and $H+K=V$

So far I have tried :

$H\subseteq V$ is a subspace $\Rightarrow\,\exists\;K=(V-H)\subseteq V$
$K$ is a subspace because it's the sum of two subspace $V$ and $(-H)$
Now we should prove that $H\cap K=0$
We assume $H\cap K\neq0\Rightarrow\exists\,\vec u\neq0\,,\,\vec u\in H\cap K$
$\vec u\in H\cap K\Rightarrow \begin{cases}\vec u\in H\\\vec u\in K\,\Rightarrow\vec u\in V-H\Rightarrow\vec u\in V,\,\vec u\notin H\end{cases}$
That's a contradiction so our hypothesis was wrong and $\vec u=0$

Comment: Whatever $V-H$ means here, I don't think that approach will work.

Comment: $0 \notin K=V-H$

Comment: We define $U+W=\{\,u+w\mid u\in U,w\in W\,\}$, but how do you define $V-H$?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're misled by the symbol $V-H$.

If it is $V-H=\{v\in V:v\notin H\}$ then it is not a subspace, because $0$ is not in this set; if it is $V-H=\{v-x:v\in V,x\in H\}$ then it's equal to $V$ so generally not contained in $H$.

The proof is by repeated selection of elements. If $H=V$, we select $K=\{0\}$ and we're done.

Otherwise there is $w_1\in V$, $w_1\notin H$. So, setting $K_1=\operatorname{Span}(w_1)$, we have $K_1\cap H=\{0\}$. If $H+K_1=V$, we're done.

Otherwise there is $w_2\in V$, $w_2\notin H+K_1$. Set $K_2=\operatorname{Span}(w_1,w_2)$ and prove

- $\{w_1,w_2\}$ is linearly independent
- $H\cap K_2=\{0\}$

This starts a recursion, so, suppose we have selected $w_1,\dots,w_{r}$ in such a way that

- $\{w_1,\dots,w_r\}$ is linearly independent
- $H\cap K_r=\{0\}$, where $K_r=\operatorname{Span}(w_1,\dots,w_r)$

If $H+K_r=V$ we're done, otherwise we can select $w_{r+1}\in V$, $w_{r+1}\notin H+K_r$ and the set $\{w_1,\dots,w_r,w_{r+1}\}$ has the properties above.

The recursion must stop, because a linearly independent set cannot have more than $\dim V$ elements.

---

If you already know that every linearly independent set can be extended to a basis, it's simpler, of course. Take $\{v_1,\dots,v_h\}$ a basis of $H$ and extend it to $\{v_1,\dots,v_h,v_{h+1},\dots,v_n\}$, a basis of $V$. Then $K=\operatorname{Span}(v_{h+1},\dots,v_n)$ is the subspace you're looking for.

Indeed, any element of $v$ can be written as
$$
v=\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_hv_h+\alpha_{h+1}+\dots+\alpha_nv_n
$$
and so
$$
v=x+y\in H+K
$$
where
$$
x=\alpha_1v_1+\dots+\alpha_hv_h\in H\qquad
\text{and}\qquad
y=\alpha_{h+1}+\dots+\alpha_nv_n\in K
$$
If $v\in H\cap K$, then
$$
v=\beta_1v_1+\dots+\beta_hv_h=\gamma_{h+1}v_{h+1}+\dots+\gamma_nv_n
$$
for some scalars. Now
$$
\beta_1v_1+\dots+\beta_hv_h+(-\gamma_{h+1})v_{h+1}+\dots+(-\gamma_n)v_n=0
$$
and so, by the linear independence,
$$
\beta_1=\dots=\beta_h=0\\
\gamma_{h+1}=\dots=\gamma_n=0
$$

and $v=0$, which implies $H\cap K = \{0\}$.

---

If the space $V$ is not finite dimensional, the result is true provided you accept Zorn's lemma. Consider the set $\mathcal{F}$ of all subspaces $L$ of $V$ satisfying $H\cap L=\{0\}$.

The set $\mathcal{F}$ can be ordered by inclusion and it's not empty, because $\{0\}\in\mathcal{F}$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a chain in $\mathcal{F}$; then
$$
L_0=\bigcup\{L:L\in\mathcal{C}\}
$$
is easily seen to be a subspace of $V$ and
$$
H\cap L_0=\bigcup\{H\cap L:L\in\mathcal{C}\}=\{0\}
$$
so $L_0\in\mathcal{F}$ and is an upper bound for $\mathcal{C}$. By Zorn's lemma we can select a maximal element $K\in\mathcal{F}$. If $H+K\ne V$, there is $w\in V$, $w\notin H+K$. But then
$$
H\cap (K+\operatorname{Span}(w))=\{0\}
$$
(proof?) and $K\subsetneq K+\operatorname{Span}(w)$, contradicting the maximality of $K$. Thus $H+K=V$ and we're done.

Comment: This wont work for infinite dimension V.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth The “recursion” method doesn't work, we need Zorn's lemma (or the equivalent axiom of choice).

Comment: @egreg yes I know that because of finite-dimensionality I can assume basis for $V$ and $H$ but how can I conclude from that the subspaces $H=Span(v_1,\dots,v_h)$ and $K =Span(v_{h+1},\dots,v_n$ have the properties mentioned or in fact how can I say that the basis of $V$ is the union of the basis of $H$ and $K$

Comment: @sepideh That $H=\operatorname{Span}(v_1,\dots,v_h)$ is true by assumption. Just apply the definitions for the rest, I'll add something.

Comment: Hello @egreg and sorry for bringing you back to this post. I wonder, in the case that $V$ is finite-dimensional, can you use the subspaces $H$ of $V$ and the corresponding $K_r$'s to reconstruct the dual $V^*$ of $V$?

Comment: @JohnnyGreen There is no “corresponding $K_r$”: there are generally infinitely many complements.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Yes, of course. My question is whether in some way, "the" complements can be used to construct the dual of the ambient vector space...It is not clear to me if the answer should be yes or no.

Comment: @JohnnyGreen I'm not sure to understand what you mean by “construct the dual”.

Comment: @egreg I mean, given a f.d. V, and solely using "the" complements of the subobjects of $V$, to produce a f.d. W which satisfies the properties that would qualify to to being called a "dual vector space to V".

Comment: @JohnnyGreen In some sense, yes. For every vector $v\in V$, choose a complement $K_v$ of $\langle v\rangle$. Then the set of these complements can be considered as the dual of $V$: for a nonzero vector $v$, identify $K_v$ with the unique linear form that has value $1$ at $v$; for $v=0$, $K_0=V$ is the zero linear form.

Comment: @egreg What do you mean by $\left< v\right>$? The subspace of all scalar multiples of $v$? This argument uses so much choice...but I guess that's quite common in these situations.

Comment: @JohnnyGreen Yes, that's it.

Comment: @egreg Ok, thank you very much!

Comment: Zorn's lemma is necessary only if $\text{codim}(H)=\infty$.

Comment: That is, if the (dimension) gap between $H$ and $V$ is infinite. Even if $V$ is infinite-dimensional, it can happen that $H$ is also infinite-dimensional while $\text{dim}(V/H)=\text{codim}(H)$ being finite. In that case, it is able to construct a finite-dimensional complement by the finite basis vectors of $V/H$.

Comment: @Thrash Yes, of course: if a vector space is finitely generated, building a bases thereof doesn't require choice.

Answer (score 4):

You should consider basis of $H$, say $\beta=\{b_i\}_{i\in I}$, extend it to a basis for $V$, say $\beta'=\{a_j\}_{j\in J}$ and take $K=\text{span}{\{\beta'-\beta\}}$

Comment: would you please explain more? I'm totally a beginner. I don't understand what you mean by extending the basis of $H$ to the basis of $V$ and then how can I conclude from that the subspace $K$ exists

Comment: Which book of linear algebra are you studying?

Comment: Gilbert Strang's

Comment: see page 109, Heading 2L

Comment: But @BhaskarVashishth the page that you mentioned above is a section about symmetric matrices not spaces and subspaces

Comment: Mmy edition can be diffrent . wait

Comment: download [this](http://m.bookzz.org/book/2064813/cb6afc) ebook and do theorem 6.45 on page 190

Comment: I personally do not like strang's book . There are many other interesting books from beginners to advanced level. You should at least explore in some library and keep one more book by your side while doing strang.