# Show that there is a subspace $U$ of $V$ such that $V \cong U \oplus W$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be a subspace of the finite-dimensional vector space $V$. Show that there is a subspace $U$ of $V$ such that $V \cong U \oplus W$

I understand that by saying $V$ is finite-dimensional means that both $U$ and $W$ are finite-dimensional as well.

I also understand that it is asking to prove that there is a $U \subset V$ such that $V$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of its subspaces $U$ and $W$. To be isomorphic it must be both injective and surjective.

I guess I'm getting confused on how to actually prove the isomorphism given the information. Is this the same as proving $V = U \oplus W$ or does the $\cong$ make a difference? How does one go about proving this?

Comment: Well $V$ is isomorphic to $V$, so if you already know or you prove that any subspace of a finite dimensional vector space has a direct complement that would be enough. Can you prove that or do you need some help?

Comment: I have found how to do so here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318837/every-subspace-of-a-vector-space-has-a-complement Thank you for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(e_i)_{i\leq m}$ a basis of $W$, we assume that $m<n$ because else $W=V$ and $U=\{0\}$, we can extend this family to a basis of $U$, by a family $(e_i)_{m+1\leq i n}$ so $U=Vect((e_i)_{m+1\leq i n})$ so 
$$
V= U\oplus W
$$
In this case we have equality because we use the constructed basis of $V$.

Comment: So $V = U \oplus W$ is the same as saying $V \cong U \oplus W$?

Comment: Yes, $V=U\oplus W$ always implies $V\cong U\oplus W$ (use the identity map as your isomorphism). Whether the other direction holds or not depends on whether you are using the internal or external direct sum, which is presumably why it's written that way.

Comment: Yes, it is the same because when you say that the sum of $U$ and $W$ is isomorphic to $V$ you are saying that sum has the same dimention of $V$ but at the same time that sum is a subspace of $V$, and those facts toogether implies that sum is equal to $V$ (if you have a subspace of $V$ with the same dimention of $V$ then that subspace is $V$)