# Proof of the existence of a complementary subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

If we let $W$ be a subspace of a vector space $V$ of finite dimension, how can I show that $W$ has a complementary subspace in $V$?

I know that I need to show there exists some $X \subseteq V$ s.t $W \cap X = \{0\}$, but I am not sure how to go about proving its existence?

Comment: possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1318837/every-subspace-of-a-vector-space-has-a-complement

Comment: Hint: Let $\{v_1,...,v_k\}$ be a basis for $W$, then adjoin this set with vectors $\{v_{k+1}...,v_n\}$ such that $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is a basis for $V$. Then let $X = \mathrm{span}(\{v_{k+1},...,v_n\})$.